# why does @font-face work on safari and not on firefox? (Mac versions)

Tags: css, firefox, safari, font-face

I've used the following in the CSS file of the website. It works on safari but not on Firefox. I'm a newbie so apologies for this if it seems like a simple question. Been trying now for 3 hours.

@font-face {
    font-family: handwriting;
    src: url(http://example.com/handwriting.ttf);
}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the font styles that use this?

Comment: "My car doesn't turn left anymore. Here, I've brought the steering wheel for you to look at." Sarcasm aside: There is no point of posting a small (randomly selected) part of your code. You need to show the whole thing in it's (non-)working order. Best is to post an URL, if necessary using a service such as http://jsfiddle.net/ .

Comment: your syntax is correct, but sometimes font files won't work right on some browser or the other (this technique is relatively new) - have you tried with different TTF files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Firefox prevents the loading of fonts served from a different domain unless they are sent with [HTTP access control headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control).

Use relative paths if you are serving the font from the same domain.  If handwriting.ttf was in the same directory as your css file then you would use this:

```
@font-face { font-family: handwriting; src: url(handwriting.ttf); }
```